# zendframework 2 does not recognize strptime()

Tags: zend-framework2

i tried calling the strptime() function within my zendframework 2 application but i got this error message:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function strptime()

this is how i called it:

```
 $dateObject = strptime(2014-04-01 , '%d-%M-%Y');
```

i am trying to convert the date to a timestamp.

Alternatively, is there another way to convert a date to a timestamp in Zend framework 2

**CORRECTION!!!!!**

Hi eveyone.its my fault; i was attempting to use the striptime() on windows platform. The documentation clearly says that it does not run on windows.

Comment: What OS are you running on? `The function is not implemented on Windows platforms`, as the docs say.

Comment: ah. so sorry. thank you for that. i was running it on windows.i will use the DateTime instead. thanks